# Pullup resistors. Does it make any difference what side of the series resistor?

Tags: resistors, impedance, digital-communications, pullup, reflection

The line is high frequency digital line. It has to be pulled up. Does the side of the series resistor make any difference?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYOitD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

or

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvTuX6.png)</sup>

Comment: It is better to put the pullup directly at the output. Otherwise you will increase the Vlow even if it will be increased  by a too small amount.

Comment: I almost always don't use the serial R2, just direct connect. I learned the tricks from the following tutorial: Electronics Tutorial: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html

Comment: This resistor (actually 20 resistors of 4.7Ohm) is required by the clients specification. (ATEX - dangerous environment)

Comment: @P__J__, many thanks for your reply.  I am interested to know why 20 k47's are required. There should be something I have been missing. Can you please give me the link to a larger part of the circuit, so that I know i learn from my mistakes.  If it is ATEX, then of course they are the pros and therefore unlikely to make any circuit design mistakes.  I only have a rusty EE diploma and earned a living for a couple of years as a electronic technician, mainly troubleshooting semiconductor testing equipment. Cheers.

Comment: I guess the 100R between the two buffers is only to protect Buf1, by limiting the current to Buf2, in case in Buf2 input is shorted to V+ or something similar. If that is the case, then I apologize for giving a unprofessionally misleading comment.

Comment: It will make a difference, but will it make a difference that is large enough to matter at all is another thing. How high is high-speed in this case, so do you have to avoid stubs or parasitic capacitance or inductance? Is there a termination resistor somewhere? Is this bi-directional bus? Push-pull output or open-drain?

Comment: Sometimes it makes a difference. Depends on context you have and we don't. I can't even tell if the signals above are inputs or outputs.

Comment: @P__J__， I read #Transistor's explanation and think that his answer is almost perfect. So there is no need to tell me more about the bigger schematic. Your question reminds me of a similar one on a power MOSFET, where there is also a series resistor to Gate, and another resistor from Gate to ground. At that time, I casually thought that it makes no difference whether the Gate resistor placed before and after. / to continue, ...

Comment: / continue, ...But then I read another expert saying that he usually ask the question in job interviews.  He gave the answer and I found his answer concise and clear, but I found it hard to repeat his answer in my broken. I need to think harder if I can do it. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 sorry but I do not know more. I guess that the reason is if there is a large current flowing through those resistors there is much lower probability of fire as combined they will have much higher power rating.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose is exactly in your circuit, especially with 20 series resistors, but one way to terminate a high-speed line is to use a series resistor such that that resistance plus the output impedance of the driver matches the characteristic impedance of the line. In that case, it's important that the series resistor is close to the driver. Placing the pull resistor close to the driver will also minimize any parasitic effects it may have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the values shown, probably not. But ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhhz7P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The two options.*

- In (a) R1 and R2 form a voltage divider. When BUF1 pulls low the voltage on the input to BUF2 will be \$ \frac {R2}{R1+R2}V+ \$.
- (b) avoids the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> *Does the side of the serial resistor make any difference?*

Not normally with the values shown but, if in doubt and you are designing a PCB, leave room for both and fit one.

Comment: it is an idea, but I just try to understand the consequences

Comment: Well, it might help if you give more information about the driver and the receiver.

Comment: uCs SPI and SDIO

Comment: It's not going to make a difference.